# How to get text from child tags which is displaying in few conditions

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I need to get a text from child tag(html tag: a) which displays only when the data entered is invalid.

if the data enetred is valid, child tag(html tag: a) doesnot display.

how to write an xpath to suit both the scenarios or how to get the text from the above html tags

HTML code looks as below:

```
<label id="pt" class="test">
some text is displayed
 <a href=javascript:void(0);>some text</a>   
Some text is displayed
</label>
```

//'a' tag displays only when there is an for the label in the UI

Answer (score 1):

You have to check for the existence of the `a` first and then get the text.

Here is the logic.

```
 // get the list of links under label
 List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//label[@id='pt']/a"));
 // check if the link exists
 if (links.size()>0) {
    //print the link text
    System.out.println(links.get(0).getText());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way

```
try
{
//if element is present do the operations for that scenario here
WebElement alerttext = driver.findelement(by.xpath("//label[@id='pt']/a[1]"));

if(alerttext.isDisplayed()){
// Print the text - alerttext.getText();
}

catch(NoSuchElementFoundException ex){
//if element is not present do the operation for that scenario here
}
```

Hope this will resolve your problem.